# Given a set of 1d-points, find the most probable periodicity that models the points (with possible omissions) as equidistant occurences

Tags: numerics, regression, curve-fitting

I try to detect interference fringes in a bunch of pictures. I projected on one axis, and I was able to detekt the peaks that indicate one of the fringes.
So now I'm having a list with points (e.g. $(100, 165, 220, 275, 341, 461, 519)$.
In the choosen example, the sought for periodicity is 60, the points scatter around $100 + 60*n$, and the 6th points was omitted).

Now the problem is how to detect this most probable periodicity of $60$? If I knew the missing points, I could simply fit with a model $m*n + b$. This fit would yield approximately $m \approx 60$ and $b \approx 100$. But I don't know these missing points, and that's why I'm looking for a better way/ better cost-function to minimize.

How would one detect this periodicity?

Comment: With waves one may think of sinus curves, which leads to Fourier. This leads to peak detection in a spectrogram or scaleogram of a continuous or discrete wavelet transform. Note that clear features of some length lead to amplitude peaks at frequencies related to that length as wavelength. Some calibration experiments may be required.